Why is $X= \mathbb{R}_{fc}$ homeomorphic to $X/A$?
I m just trying to understand the following fact. I read the corresponding section in Topology by Munkres a few times but simply cannot understand how:
Let $X= \mathbb{R}_{fc}$ be the finite complement topology on the set of real numbers. Let $A\subset X$ be a closed subset. We define the equivalence relation: $\sim: \forall x,y \in X: x \sim y \iff (x=y $ or $ x,y \in A)$.
I see that $A$ must contain a finite amount of points, since it is closed in $X$. But I don’t see what a possible homeomorphism $ \varphi : X \to X/A$ could look like if $A$ contains more than one point, since a homeomorphism is a bijection by definition. I would greatly appreciate any attempt to help me and explain me the reason, why that is, or point me to a specific key fact that leads to that conclusion.
Thank you in advance
Edit I realized now that being injective for the potential homeomorphism is in respect to $\sim$ and not to $=$. So I tried the following attempt: $$\varphi: X/A \to X: \{x\} \mapsto (x \text{ if }\{x\} \neq \{A\}, a_0 \text{ otherwise})$$
For a fixed $a_0 \in A$ but now it doesn’t seem to be surjective anymore? If I replace $a_0$ with $A$ then I don’t have a well-defined function anymore. Can anybody give me a hint?

Could you specify which section of Munkres you are referring to?

I ve read the section 22 about Quotient Topology, but couldn't find anything that could help me further.

Trying to find a specific map between $X$ and $X/A$ is a colossal task. Instead, we can show the existence of such bijection via cardinality arguments.
We know that $X$ is uncountable with cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. On the other hand, by how it is defined the binary realtion, $X/A$ consists of the same points of $X$, except the points of $A$ are "blended" in a unique "point" (the equivalence class of $A$). Since $A$ is closed, by the definition of the cofinite topology, $A$ is finite. Letting $n=|A|$ and by the properties of the cardinality of the continuum, $|X/A|=\mathfrak{c}-(n-1)=\mathfrak{c}$. Hence, $X$ and $X/A$ has the same cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, which is equivalent to say that there exists a bijection $\varphi:X\to X/A$.
What is more, let us study the topology of $X/A$. It is the quotient topology given by the canonical map $\pi:X\to X/A$. Hence, by the definition of the quotient topology, $D\subseteq X/A$ is closed if and only if $\pi^{-1}(D)\subseteq X$ is closed (i.e., finite by the cofinite topology). However, $\pi^{-1}(D)=D$ if $D$ does not contain any point of $A$ and $\pi^{-1}(D)=D\cup A$ otherwise. Hence, $D$ is closed if and only if $D$ or $D\cup A$ are finite, implying that $D$ is finite. In other words, the topology of $X/A$ is also the cofinite topology.
Finally, since $\varphi$ is a bijection, a way to show that $\varphi$ is homeomorphic is checking that $C\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $\varphi(C)\subseteq X/A$ is closed. By the previous paragraph, this is the same as checking that $C$ is finite if and only if $\varphi(C)$ is finite. Since bijective maps preserve finiteness, we are done.
